# ';' expected and illegal start of expression error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm java programming in linux but it reports the following error. Can someone help me out? Thanks in anticipation!

```
Break.java:4: ';' expected  
    for (int x:numbers) {  
              ^  
Break.java:11: illegal start of expression  
  }  
  ^  
2 errors
```

```
public class Break {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] numbers={10,20,30,40,50};
        for (int x:numbers){
            if (x==30){
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(x);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What java version are you using? If it's less than Java 1.5, you can't use enhanced for loop.

Comment: For this line `int [] numbers={10,20,30,40,50};` it should probably be `int [] numbers = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50};`

Comment: @DennisMeng - No need for `new int[]` when using an array initializer expression. See "Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array" in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: It [Works for me](http://pastebin.com/04Y8KNEH) - there must be something else at hand.  Which version of java are you using? (`javac -version`)

Comment: @TedHopp Huh, could've sworn I've had issues doing that before. I guess it was some other thing I'd overlooked.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely 1.4 issues.

Comment: I use java 1.4.2. I think that's the problem. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must be using JDK 1.4 or before.  Your code compiles in 1.5, but not in 1.4:

```
$ javac Break.java
$ javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 Break.java
Break.java:4: for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.4
(try -source 1.5 to enable for-each loops)
    for (int x:numbers){
              ^
1 error
```

You must use Java 1.5+ to use the foreach loop syntax, [which was introduced in Java 1.5](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html).